# Best Way to make a Windows Forms scalable?

Tags: c#, winforms

What would be the best way to make a WinForms application fully scalable, for example when the Form resizes?

In WPF i would use something like a `Viewbox` and/or a `UniformGrid`, but something like this doesn't exists in WinForms.

Is there an easier (and maybe faster) way to rescale controls on a from after resizing it, instead of resizing them all by calculating their new Size/Location etc.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Forms, you use the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties for each control.

Here's an article about using them: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/

You should also look at [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) and [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much... FlowPanel seems to bee exactly what i need

Answer (score 2):

you can use `anchor` and `dock`, depending on your need:

- **Anchor** - the edges of the container to which a control is bound and determines how a control is resized with its parent.
- **Dock** - which control borders are docked to its parent control and determines how a control is resized with its parent.

for further read: [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `Anchor` property found on pretty much any control. This allows you to lock a control to any (or all) of the four borders of a window.

Once one distance is anchored (e.g. `Top` or `Right`), the control will always try to keep that distance, no matter how you resize your window.

For example, you'd set `Anchor` to `Bottom` and `Right` for a button that is supposed to always stay in the bottom right corner of a window. A text box, that should always fill the window from left to right would use `Left` and `Right`.

Similar things can be achieved utilizing `Dock`, but a docked control will always try to fill as much space as possible (there are different strategies available, like "fill everything from here and upwards) based on its container. Depending on your use case, this can however be a lot harder to control (and I usually only use it if I want a single control to fill a full window, e.g. a `TextBox`).

If you need more complex alignment, like widths scaled on some kind of ratio (e.g. 30%), then there are several different containers available.